# Parts of the image disappear and rotation doesn't work using matrix operations

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-rotation

I am trying to randomly scale and rotate an image using the imageview matrix, see code below. I am experiencing two problems, that may or may not be related.

First: The rotation doesn't work, the image appears without any rotation.

Second: The scaling works, to the extent that the image is rescaled. However, if the scale constant is larger than one, part of the image is cut away, so that only part of the image appear on the screen. I assume this has something to do with the borders of the imageView, but how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    final ImageView imageView = getImageView(); //Help function that provides imageViews
    if(imageView == null) return;

    Matrix imageMatrix = imageView.getImageMatrix(); 
    imageMatrix.postRotate(randGen.nextFloat()*360);
    float randomScale = randGen.nextFloat()*1.5f + 0.5f;
    imageMatrix.postScale(randomScale, randomScale);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(usedBitmap);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(imageMatrix);
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layPar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layPar.leftMargin = pCenter.x; //pCenter is the point where the image is drawn.
    layPar.topMargin = pCenter.y;
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView, layPar);
```

UPDATE: I've had this problem for a while now, I didn't fin a solution using the above approach, so I tried subclassing View instead. This is my View subclass, the image appears neither rotated nor scaled. I really don't see why these solutions don't work. Anyone?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class ScaleRotateView extends View {

    Bitmap image;
    float rotation;
    float scaleX;
    float scaleY;

    public ScaleRotateView(Context context, Bitmap image, float rotation, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
        super(context);
        this.image = image;
        this.rotation = rotation;
        this.scaleX = scaleX;
        this.scaleY = scaleY;

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, new Paint());
        Matrix matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
        matrix.preRotate(rotation, image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2);
        matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);
        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);

                //I also tried using canvas.rotate() and canvas.scale, but to no avail.
    }

}
```

Comment: I just tried your code and the rotation worked fine. Used a 4.0.4 device though.

Comment: I use my htc desire to test, and the rotations doesn't work. I would like the app to be runnable on the desire generation of devices. What am I doing wrong? Did you experience parts of the image not being drawn, Sandis?

Comment: Yes, sometimes parts of the image was not drawn. But this was most likely since the canvas tried to paint the image outside of the views boundary, and this should not be your issue since your image is not rotated. The solution for me would be to place the image in a bigger view. Unfortunately I don't know why your image does not rotate :/

Answer (score 0):

You can jsut try inside the onDraw method of your custom view

```
 Matrix transform = new Matrix();
 transform.setTranslate(dx, dy);//
 transform.preRotate(degree,PivotX ,PivotY);
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, transform, null);
```